# Error while starting a WPF-Application on System-Startup

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, visual-studio-2019

I have a WPF-Application that I would like to start automatically if I start my Computer.

I have a window where a user can configure some settings for the application, one of the possible configuration options is a checkbox, that allows the user to dis- or enable the application to automatically start on the System-Startup.

This is how I set or delete the value in the Registry, depending on the users choice in the Checkbox:

```
try
        {
            var currentAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            var rkApp = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run", true);

            if (settingsViewModel.AutostartEnabled)
            {
                rkApp.SetValue(currentAssembly.GetName().Name, currentAssembly.Location);
            }
            else
            {
                rkApp.DeleteValue(currentAssembly.GetName().Name, false);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
        }
```

My Problem is, that even though the Application gets registered and can also be seen in the Autostart-Section within the Task-Manager, that I get the following error every time I restart my computer to check if the Appliction is started:

"You are attempting to open a file of type Application extension (.dll)"

So what am I doing wrong? Is there any way to avoid this error or to fix it? I already tried adding an application manifest file to my project to always start my Application as an Administrator. But that didn't seem to work either.

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: What's the value of currentAssembly.Location?

Comment: currentAssembly.Location has the following value:
"C:\\Users\\Username\\source\\repos\\AppName\\AppName\\AppNameCore\\bin\\Debug\\netcoreapp3.1\\AppName.dll"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName` instead of `currentAssembly.Location`.

This should give you the path of the running executable. `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly` does not.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This gave me the path I've been loking for.